# Finding the domain of $\frac{1}{x}|x^2 - 1|$

Tags: limits, functions, continuity

What is the domain of this function

$F(x)=\frac{1}{x}|x^2 - 1|$

Can someone please tell me how to find it ?

Comment: Is it $\frac{1}{x|x^2-1|}$ or $\frac{1}{x}|x^2-1|$?

Comment: Where do things "go bad" (division by $0$)?

Comment: I edited your question to add [MathJax formatting](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). If this isn't the function you meant, feel free to correct it.

Comment: @DylanSp: I'm betting on $\dfrac{1}{x|x^2-1|}$.

Comment: @TonyK It's entirely possible; I edited the original statement back in to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean $F(x)=\frac{1}{x|x^2-1|}$.

Notice that $x|x^2-1|=x\cdot|x-1|\cdot|x+1|$.

Now $x\cdot|x-1|\cdot|x+1|=0$ exactly when $x=-1,0$, or $1$.  For those values of $x$ the function is not defined because you can't divide by zero.  So the domain is all other values of $x$, namely $(-\infty,-1)\cup(-1,0)\cup(0,1)\cup(1,\infty)$.

Comment: Could also be written $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{-1, 0, 1\}$.

Comment: @BrianTung Yes, that's true.